# How do I install the VCAC (VMware) guest agent on Ubuntu? I have an rpm file to use

Tags: package-management, software-installation, vmware, alien

I am using Ubuntu 15.  I have an rpm package for installing the gugent (guest agent for VMware's Virtual Cloud Automation Center).  I'm trying to find a standalone (offline) installation package for gettext and alien (for the rpm file).  I have installed alien.  But it never works.  I get an error about rpm command not found whenever I use alien.  For gettext, I have a .tar.xz file.  I'm not sure if it is properly installed.  I'd rather use a .deb file for installing gettext.  For some reason, I think it may be a dependency to alien working properly.  Alien's man page works.  So alien is installed.

Is there an alternative to alien?

I understand that "customization" is not supported with the Guest Agent on Ubuntu.  What is customization in this context?  Vmware mentions Ubuntu and the VCAC.  But I cannot seem to find how to install the agent.

Edit: I'm not looking to install VMware Tools.  I want to install the VCAC guest agent on Ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 15.04 or 15.10?

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to install the Vmware guest tools inside an Ubuntu guest, the easy way is to open a terminal and enter

`sudo apt-get install --install-suggests open-vm-tools`

Alternatively, the Vmware tools can can be run from the installation disks that Vmware was installed from, but the process is a little involved, and I believe that there are some patches needed for the Ubuntu 15 installations.  VMWare's documentation does indicate that on a linux guest, open-vm-tools should be used.

Comment: This is close.  But I want to install the vCAC guest agent.  VMware tools are already installed.

Comment: @Kiran Have you tried asking over at the [VMWare community?](https://communities.vmware.com/welcome)